# How to query a Postgres `RECORD` datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sqldatatypes

I have a query that will return a row as a `RECORD` data type from a subquery - see below for example:

```
select *
from (
    select row(st.*) table_rows
    from some_table st
) x
where table_rows[0] = 339787
```

I am trying to further qualify it in the `WHERE` clause and I need to do so by extracting one of the nodes in the returned `RECORD` data type.

When I do the above, I get an error saying:

```
ERROR:  cannot subscript type record because it is not an array
```

Does anybody know of a way of implementing this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `row` in `postgres` but can you just move the `where` criteria to the subquery instead and filter on the needed field?

Comment: Yes, I could but that wouldn't fit in the query I am trying to work with. The above is a simplification of it and it were that simple, then yes of course I could simply have done that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `(row).column_name`. You can just refer to the table itself to create the record:

```
select *
from (
    select r
    from some_table r
) x
where (r).column_name = 339787
```

There is a small chance that later a column is created with the same name as the alias you chose and the above query will fail as `select r` will return the later created column in instead of the record. The first solution is to use the `row` constructor as you did in your question:

```
select row(r.*) as r
```

The second solution is to use the schema qualified name of the table:

```
select my_squema.some_table as r
```

Comment: Note: If you have a column in a table with a name that equals alias on your table, you will get that column, not the entire row in the output.

Comment: @KamilG. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately You can try this

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from tbl
) x
where x.col_name = 339787
```